# Slow mongo $geoWithin query

Tags: mongodb

I have created a collection with approx 5mil documents. When i preform a basic geoWithin query in an area with a lot of geometries (~1 mil in an area at the size of a city), the query takes over 2 minutes to execute and returns 40k documents. When I preform another query in a much wider area with the same amount of result it takes less then a second.

I thought maybe the problem was with one of the geometries in the small area search, so i inserted them all into an empty collection and preformed the same search. It was fast.

Is there any way i can make this query work faster? 
I've checked and all the queries use the 2dsphere index created on the revelant field.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do your documents look like and what does the query look like?

Comment: The documents have between 18-26 different elements. All of the fields are basic value fields, except the shape field of course.

Comment: The documents have between 18-26 different elements. All of the fields are basic value fields, except the shape field of course. The query goes like this: db.daniel.find({"shape" : {"$geoWithin" : {"$geometry" : {"type" : "polygon", "coordinates" : [[[24.37, 38.88], [24.37, 38.89], [24.41, 38.89], [24.41, 38.88], [24.37, 38.88]]]}}}})

Comment: Have you run the query with [.explain()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) at the end as this will show you what is happening in the query

Comment: Yes i have, all the values are equal between the explains on the queries, except nscanned and nScannedAllPlans which are twice as much in the slower query. Btw, the environment is sharded...

Comment: Can you include a sample document as well as the `explain()` output?  Hard to guess what's happening without more information.